# Как применяются индексы в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Я использую MSSQL  Server 2016.  К примеру есть таблица.

```
CREATE TABLE table (column1 int,column2 nvarchar(20) column3 nvarchar(20));
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX col1 on table (column1 asc); 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX col2 on table (column2 asc);
```

Есть запросы:

1. `Select * from Table`
2. `Select column3 from Table`
3. `Select column1,column2 from Table`
4. `Select column1,column3 from Table` итд...

Мне непонятно в каком случае индексы будут применяться, а в каком нет и как связанно применение индексов в зависимости от того кластеризованный он или нет? Если есть хорошая статья буду благодарен.

Comment: когда добавите `where column1=1` или `order by column1` тогда и будут применяться, а в ваших примерах полной выборке эти индексы вообще толку не имеют никакого

Comment: @teran хорошо `Select column3 from Table where column3=1` будет ли в этом случае применяться индекс и почему?

Comment: @ruslan Не будет, индекс может использоваться только при поиске (реже, сортировке) по колонке, которая есть в индексе. Либо, если бы вы написали `select column1 from tab` индекс мог бы использоваться в режиме полного сканирования _вместо_ обращения к данным, так как в индексе col1 есть вся необходимая информация

Comment: То, когда применимы индексы, а когда - неприменимы, напрямую зависит от их физической структуры. Почитайте https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190457(v=sql.105).aspx (есть в ответе ниже) + https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms180978(v=sql.105).aspx. Там все очень подробно расписано, с картинками и примерами.

Answer (score 3):

В первую очередь предлагаю ознакомиться с выдержкой из [статьи на сайте Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190457(v=sql.105).aspx):

**Как оптимизатор запросов использует индексы**
Правильно построенные индексы могут сократить количество дисковых операций ввода-вывода, уменьшить потребление системных ресурсов, таким образом улучшая производительность запроса. Индексы могут быть полезны во множестве запросов, содержащих инструкции SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE или MERGE. Рассмотрим запрос SELECT Title, HireDate FROM HumanResources.Employee WHERE EmployeeID = 250 в базе данных База данных AdventureWorks2008R2. При выполнении этого запроса оптимизатор запросов оценивает все доступные методы получения данных и выбирает наиболее эффективный метод. Этим методом может являться просмотр таблицы или просмотр одного или более индексов, если они существуют.

При выполнении просмотра таблицы оптимизатор запросов считывает все строки таблицы и извлекает строки, удовлетворяющие критериям запроса. Просмотр таблицы формирует много дисковых операций ввода-вывода и может быть ресурсоемкой операцией. Но если результирующий набор запроса содержит высокий процент строк таблицы, то просмотр таблицы может оказаться самым эффективным методом.

Когда оптимизатор запросов использует индекс, он выполняет поиск по ключевым столбцам индекса, находит место хранения запрашиваемых строк и извлекает оттуда совпадающие строки. В основном поиск по индексу протекает намного быстрее, чем поиск по таблице, так как в отличие от таблицы индекс часто содержит мало столбцов в каждой строке и строки расположены в отсортированном порядке.

Оптимизатор запросов обычно выбирает наиболее эффективный метод при выполнении запросов. Но если отсутствуют доступные индексы, оптимизатор запросов должен использовать просмотр таблицы. Важной задачей является проектирование и создание таких индексов, которые наилучшим образом впишутся в окружение, чтобы для оптимизатора запросов существовали эффективные индексы, из которых можно сделать выбор. SQL Server предоставляет компонент помощник по настройке ядра СУБД, который помогает проанализировать среду базы данных и выбрать соответствующие индексы.

---

Очень хорошо про индексы объясняет Дмитрий Короткевич в своем видео-докладе:

1. [Индексы и все, все, все (Часть 1)](http://sqlcom.ru/video/stuff/all-about-indexes-part-1/)
2. [Индексы и все, все, все (Часть 2)](http://sqlcom.ru/video/stuff/all-about-indexes-part-2/)

---

Теперь постараюсь кратко ответить на ваши вопросы:

1. Для приведенных вами запросов созданные на таблице индексы использоваться не будут.
2. В данном запросе будет использоваться индекс **col1**: `Select column1 from Table`
3. Следующий индекс сможет ускорить **запрос №3**: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX col1 on table (column1 asc) INCLUDE column2`
4. Кластерный индекс изменяет структуру таблицы-кучи (heap table) и на листовом уровне хранит данные строк таблицы, кластерный индекс для таблицы может быть только **1**. **Важное дополнение**: `Clustered Index Scan` в плане запроса - сканирование всей таблицы, т.е. поиск по индексу не используется, поиск - всегда `Seek`.
5. Некластерный индекс является самостоятельным объектом, может иметь секцию include и хранить на листовых уровнях значения выбранных столбцов таблицы.