# Важен ли порядок при создании покрывающего индекса в Microsoft SQL?

Tags: sql-server, запрос, index

Если запрос выглядит следующим образом

```
SELECT 
    Customers.Last_Name,
    Customers.First_Name,
    Customers.Email
FROM
    Customers
WHERE
    Customers.Last_Name BETWEEN 'Roland' AND 'Smith'
```

, то важен ли порядок столбцов при создании покрывающего индекса?
А точнее, должен ли он быть таким для максимальной эффективности?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Customer_Email] ON [dbo].[Customers] 
(
            [Last_Name] ASC,
            [First_Name] ASC,
            [Email_Address] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Чтобы индекс мог эффективно использоваться для приведенного запроса, столбец `Last_Name` должен быть первым в индексе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала предлагаю разобраться что такое **покрывающий индекс**, приведу выдержку из статьи на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/247373/):

> **Зачем использовать покрывающий индекс взамен составного индекса?**
> Во-первых, давайте убедимся, что мы понимаем различие между ними.
> **Составной индекс** это просто обычный индекс, в который включено больше одного столбца. Несколько ключевых столбцов может
> использоваться для обеспечения уникальности каждой строки таблицы,
> также возможен вариант, когда первичный ключ состоит из нескольких
> столбцов, обеспечивающих его уникальность, или вы пытаетесь
> оптимизировать выполнение часто вызываемых запросов к нескольким
> столбцам. В общем, однако, чем больше ключевых столбцов содержит
> индекс, тем менее эффективна работа этого индекса, а значит составные
> индексы стоит использовать разумно.
>
> Как было сказано, запрос может извлечь огромную выгоду, если все необходимые данные сразу расположены на листьях индекса, как и сам
> индекс. Это не проблема для кластеризованного индекса, т.к. все данные
> уже там (вот почему так важно хорошенько подумать когда вы создаете
> кластеризованный индекс). Но некластеризованный индекс на листьях
> содержит только ключевые столбцы. Для доступа ко всем остальным данным
> оптимизатору запросов необходимы дополнительные шаги, что может
> вызвать значительные дополнительные накладные расходы для выполнения
> ваших запросов.
>
> Вот где **покрывающий индекс** спешит на помощь.
> Когда вы определяете некластеризованный индекс, то можете указать
> дополнительные столбцы к вашим ключевым.

Таким образом покрывающий индекс не должен содержать все выбираемые столбцы запроса в структуре дерева индекса, а только те, которые будут использованы для фильтрации или группировки данных в запросе, остальные столбцы из секции `SELECT` должны быть помещены в `INCLUDE` раздел индекса.

Возможно вам будет полезен ответ из другого вопроса на [StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737961/263975)

---

В приведенном примере использован составной индекс из 3 полей, а не покрывающий индекс, код для создания покрывающего индекса будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Customer_Email] ON [dbo].[Customers]  (
   [Last_Name] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([First_Name], [Email_Address]) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

### Отвечая на ваш вопрос:

для покрывающего индекса порядок столбцов в секции `INCLUDE` **не важен**, **но важен порядок столбцов для составного индекса**, т.к. данные колонок помещаются в дерево индекса по порядку перечисления столбцов и оптимизатор запроса не сможет использовать индекс из 2 колонок для поиска значений только 2 колонки. Наглядный пример того, как будет выглядеть структура индекса из 2 колонок (EMPLOYEE_ID, SUBSIDIARY_ID) вы можете увидеть на рисунке:

[image: Структура составного индекса]

Рисунок заимствован из англоязычной статьи про [составные индексы](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys) за авторством *Markus Winand*

Comment: Довольно спорная, на мой взгляд, у Шелдона терминология. В других источниках, пожалуй и не встретишь такого. В основном, как раз, покрывающим индексом называют индекс, который содержит все необходимые для запроса столбцы. В этом смысле, индекс в вопросе - покрывающий, хотя и не оптимальный.

Comment: _"Если индекс содержит все столбцы, ссылаемые в запросе, это называется покрытием запроса."_  © [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj835095(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: "покрывающий индекс не должен содержать все выбираемые столбцы запроса в структуре дерева индекса, а только те, которые будут использованы для фильтрации или группировки данных в запросе, остальные столбцы из секции SELECT должны быть помещены в INCLUDE раздел индекса." - это не всегда оптимальное решение. кроме фильтрации и группировки индекс дает сортировку при скане по нему, так что иногда колонки помещают в конец не-include части ради сортировки или возможности merge join выше по плану выполнения.